# Can anyone help correct my bash script: Custom user creation in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I've got basic knowledge of bash scripting, and need to create a function to create a user with custom settings:
1.User name and password
2.Group and user ID
3.Comment
4.Home directory

```
`function user_custom {
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] ; then
read -p "Enter name here: " username
read -s -p "Enter password: " password
grep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0]; then
echo -e "${LIGHTGREEN}This user already exists! Try another name 
please.${RESET}" ; break
else
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt(($AVG[0], "password")' $password)
read -p "Enter group for user: "GID
egrep "^$GID" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0] ; then
$GID=$?
else
echo "No such group"
fi
read -p "Enter custom comment for $username: "comment
read -p "Enter unique user ID" Uid
getent passwd `grep "^Uid" /proc/$3/status |awk '{printf "%4s",$2}'` | if 
[$? -eq $Uid ] ; then
echo "Select diferent ID"
fi
useradd -m -p -u -c -g $username $pass $Uid $comment $GID
fi
```

}`

I have a function ready, but I'm sure there are a lot of obvious mistakes.
Its like a patched skirt, I've gathered a lot of data from different sources.

[image]

I would be thankful if someone could help with fixing it.
Ill provide a screenshot of the whole function.

I'm from Ukraine, but i am good at english\russian.

PS: btw the 'if' in the end is included, all ifs are closeTd

Thanks ahead! <3

Comment: Add code as text not as link to an image

Comment: ok alright, im just out of time

Comment: You forgot the part where you actually describe the problem.  "Here's a picture of some code, can you help me fix it?" isn't really an answerable question.  What actual indication of a problem do you have?

Comment: This whole function does not work correctly, and im trying to get help online

Comment: @СтаніславДомащук: You might start here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Just saying "it does not work correctly" doesn't tell us anything about the problem.  What does it do?  What do you expect it to do?  At what point does the behavior of the code differ from what you expect?  Nobody here can see your screen or read your mind, you have to describe the problem in order for anybody to help.

Answer (score 0):

I correct it for you, I hope this will suit your need. You had lot of typo like `if [ anything ]; then` there is always needed space after [ and before ]. 
Brake only working for loops, you need to use exit 1 to terminate function with error code 1.

Instead of encrypt password in the script I prefer let passwd do the job, it will also enforce password rules.

The following way you can pass almost everything to command, like you typed it in from console:

```
(echo $password ; echo $password ) | passwd $username
```

I would add a lot of other check to make this script to enforce followings:

- Uid should be number, and less/equal than UID_MAX in /etc/login.def
- Gid should be a number, and less than the GID_MAY in /etc/login.def

And some feature as well like:

- The script cannot handle if you like to make a GID for the user insted of using a existing one.
- Asking if it should create home folder or not (currently -m do it in useradd)
- If passwd fail because of password rule enforcing on the host, there is no retrying so you need to type it manually.

This is just the ones came into my mind now but there could be more.

```
#!/bin/bash

function user_custom  {
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ] ; then
        read -p "Enter name here: " username ;
        read -s -p "Enter password: " password ; echo
        grep "^$username" /etc/passwd > /dev/null
                if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo -e "\nThis user already exists! Try another name please.\n" ; exit 1
                else
                        read -p "Enter group for user: " GID
                        egrep "^"$GID":" /etc/group > /dev/null
                                if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then
                                        echo "No such group ( "$GID" )"; exit 1
                                fi
                        read -p "Enter custom comment for $username: " comment
                        read -p "Enter unique user ID: " Uid ; echo
                        if [ $(getent passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $3}' | egrep -c "^"$Uid"$" ) -gt 0 ];then
                                        echo " ID already exist! " ; exit 1
                        fi
                fi
useradd -m -u $Uid -c $comment -g $GID $username &&
(echo $password ; echo $password ) | passwd $username
fi
}

user_custom
```